# How to parse multiple JSON data from single stream in Java continuously?

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have a InputStreamReader (connected to a socket), which will receive multiple JSON document data.  For example, it will have

```
{ "name" : "foo" }
```

and, some times later (without connection closed), the stream will have another JSON data,

```
{ "name" : "bar" }
```

.

I want to parse it in my processing loop with json-simple or json-smart, whatever.  Is there anyway to do this?

I like to have a JSON parser (input data from a stream) and if it does not received data from the stream, the parser can block for more data, and if it receives a complete JSON data (possibly with some method), it can continuously parse the next JSON data.

Apprently, I tried with json-simple, and json-smart but no success.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly then the problem is parsing a complete `JSON` object from a batch of `JSON` object (continuously coming through an input stream).

So, If it is possible to detect that a complete `JSON` object have been received, we can parse that object.

To detect if the received `JSON` object (`String`) is complete and valid, we can maintain a `Stack` of `{`, and `}` <sup>1</sup>. For every `{` we receive we can push it on `Stack`, and for every `}`, we can remove an `{` from `Stack`. And if we have the `Stack` empty (not first time) we can conclude that there is a complete `JSON` object. We can then proceed to parse.

**1** - Not sure about parentheses structure (is it balanced?) of `JSON`, didn't explore `JSON` formation deeply earlier :(.

Comment: What if any of JSON string value contains unmatched parentheses?  And if I write code to do that, it looks like a duplication of JSON parsing in my code and what-ever JSON parser. :(

Comment: :(. Then creating a `JSON` object from the string value without getting an Exception can tell us about the validity.